# Programatically disable orange/blue highlight around links in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

There have been a few posts about disabling the focus highlighting in Android's WebView which usually involves adding the following to the web page:-

```
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}
```

Is there any way to set these styles programatically for any web page that is displayed in the web view?

Alternatively, are there any API calls that control the appearance (or lack of) of the focus overlay?